# How to get list of scripts in html document head

Tags: javascript, html

We can access all styleSheets using `document.styleSheets`. What is the alternative to access all scripts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a list of scripts you can use

- document.getElementsByTagName("script");
- document.scripts;
- document.querySelectorAll("script");

  ```
  window.onload=function() {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++) {
      if (scripts[i].src)
        console.log(i,scripts[i].src);
      else 
        console.log(i,scripts[i].innerHTML);
   }
  }
  ```

[DEMO](http://window.onload=function()%20%7B%20%20%20var%20scripts%20=%20document.getElementsByTagName(%22script%22);%20%20%20for%20(var%20i=0;i%3Cscripts.length;i++)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(scripts[i].src)%20console.log(i,scripts[i].src)%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20console.log(i,scripts[i].innerHTML)%20%20%20%7D%20%7D)

Answer (score 3):

You can try `document.querySelectorAll('script')`:

```js
let scripts = [...document.querySelectorAll('script')];
console.log(scripts);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/1"></script>
    <script src="/2"></script>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.querySelectorAll('script')` Will return an **Nodelist** of all scripts, for example:

```js
const scripts = document.querySelectorAll('script');

console.log(scripts);

console.log(scripts[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You then can access individual scripts by their index.

Comment: [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) does **not** return an Array. It returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). These are *very* different.

Comment: This node **not** just return them from `<head>` but all scripts!